# How can I reset Compiz settings to default?

Tags: unity, compiz, reset

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring)

I've installed CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM) and wanted to enable the wobbling window effect. This disabled some other things and suddenly I didn't have window borders any more...
Following various instructions I found at Google, I've tried the following steps:

1. Go to CCSM Preferences / Reset to defaults

This disabled all plugins and effects (including Unity) so I didn't get any further...

2. executing `dconf reset -f /org/compiz` and rebooting

This brought borders back, but still don't have close/mini/maxi buttons, can't resize or move windows. And the top left entries of the menu bar vanished (Logout, battery, volume...) so I have to shutdown my computer via a terminal...

**Edit:**

3. Following the instructions from the first answer.

This brought my menu bar applets back...
`dpkg-reconfigure` didn't seem to work. Result of this command:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 1: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [general]: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 2: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [gnome_session]: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 7: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: integration: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: profile: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 11: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [general_ubuntu]: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: integration: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 15: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: profile: not found
```

Is there any possibility to reset the settings like they were after installing Ubuntu?

**Edit 2:**

Just noticed that the title bar of windows isn't missing; It's just hidden under the menu bar. So the buttons are only hidden, too.

**Edit 3: PROBLEM SOLVED**

Started CCSM, went to window management and checked scale windows and move windows... After a re-login everything was fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Execute the following command and then re-login:

```
rm  -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1
```

Comment: I think it will remove all settings, not only unity

Comment: Then you only rm .compiz-1 and .config/compiz-1

Comment: Maybe you should revise this answer as per your comment above... I used to see **Ubuntu's default background for one or two seconds on startup**. Removing `~/.compiz` and `~/.config/compiz-1` got rid of this problem as well (although I still see it after logoff and login). Thanks :-)

Comment: or you can easily create a new profile or set it to default

Answer (score 5):

The script is now bundled with Unity Tweak Tool. You can install it using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

To reset Unity, do

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

Comment: This worked (eventually, had to log in and out, set `DISPLAY=:0`)! Thank you! No thanks to unity being flaky and unfriendly.

Answer (score 3):

You probably are missing this last command:

```
unity --reset-icons
```

Look at this link:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/04/how-to-restart-unity-and-compiz-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/

Hope it helps

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't show any effect after relog/reboot

Comment: This is the command that saved it for me!

Answer (score 3):

what worked for me is the solution described in the link posted by Mário:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/04/how-to-restart-unity-and-compiz-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/

Steps:

```
 sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
 dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
 unity --reset-icons
```

and login again

Answer (score 2):

Open a Terminal and type:

$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure compiz

an relogin...

or type in Terminal for compiz standard:

$ gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz
$ rm -rf ~/.compiz

Comment: This brought the menu bar applets back... the other problems remain.