# Reset compiz from command-line

Tags: 13.10, compiz, window-manager, window

I am considering enabling the ring switcher (or other) effects that come along with compiz extras on my Ubuntu 13.10. The default app switcher is not that much to my liking  - navigating multiple windows of a same app is clumsy as hell and overall it's very old school.

So when I am about to add the ring switcher to replace the default alt-tab behavior, 
an intimidating :) question about whether I choose to ignore or resolve conflicts show up. Would there be a way for me to reset all this setup back from the command-line in case that renders my server desktopless as some people have reported about other kinds of compiz fiddling? there's a whole slew of stuff at [How can I reset Compiz settings to default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348438/how-can-i-reset-compiz-settings-to-default) and I really wonder which of them is the clean way if any.

Also will applying this change still be safe once I'd upgrade to the future Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Also other ways to spice up the part of navigating between all open windows in a smoother way, without configuring compiz! would be most welcome. As far as I understand, compiz is enabled in Ubuntu by default, but only the configuration utility of it is not. I hope this understanding is correct.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://askubuntu.com/a/36165/9598 ??

Comment: that's an ancient thread, can't be applicable to today's versions.... and I haven't screwed anything and trying to roll back, rather checking WHETHER there's a safe way to before diving into changes.

Comment: I would give it a try. I know it is an ancient thread. But Compiz has not changed a lot since these days. It might work even if you haven screwed anything. Unfortunately I am not using 13.10 and I can't reproduce the results. Sorry if this doesn't help you. Good luck!

Comment: @matt have you tried my answer?

Comment: Luckily didn't ultimately get to screw up my settings... Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 4):

first install dconf-tools

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

reset Compiz and Unity by using the following command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

restart Unity after running the above command

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: If Unity/Compiz is so misconfigured, that you can't execute commands in graphical mode any more, refer to [How to run commands if unity is not working?](/q/333007).