# Start computer, no launcher, no side panel and hot keys don't work.

Tags: unity, compiz, plugins

So after I log in nothing appears, just the background. Can't manage to open up a terminal with Ctrl-Alt t. Nothing
This happen after I mistakenly click an option in effects in Compiz. 
I saw a couple previous threads that look similar but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: Try "Ctrl Alt F4" for the root terminal, what OS are you running and how was it installed?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but you can try:

When bootig up your PC press Shift to force show the Grub. Then start to command line and login to your user. Then type:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
```

That should reset Compiz to defaults.

Comment: I did, but it told me that dconf failed to commit changes: connection refused.

Comment: Mmm, im new to Ubuntu, so not sure. But you may find this thread usefull: http://askubuntu.com/a/371644 the chosen anwser suggest to delete some stuff so i can only say to be carefull. Try first just deleting the configuration files for only Compiz 'rm /home/youruser/.config/compiz-1' since is the configuration on your user, it should be a safe procedure.