# Ubuntu 15.04 black window border

Tags: windows, 15.04, borders

I just updated to ubuntu 15.04 and all my windows have a black border.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Your WM (Windows Manager) does not correctly draw border around your window. What desktop are you using ? which WM ?

Comment: Looks like Unity. Does Unity use Compiz? If yes, try [resetting Compiz](http://askubuntu.com/questions/348438/how-can-i-reset-compiz-settings-to-default).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the black borders after upgrading to 15.04... i switched from Nvidia 340 to 346 and back and ran the following

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

You might try just running the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I always have the same problem after resuming from suspend. I've found three different solutions.

<strike>-   Change the appearance theme to something else and back from the command line. Eg. if your current theme is "Ambiance":</strike>

```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Radiance";
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Ambiance";
```

[edit - the above only fixes currently open windows.]

- Run `unity --replace` from a terminal or the Run Command Prompt (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>). This will reinitialize Unity, which will take a few seconds, but you shouldn't lose any work.

  [image]
- Install and run CompizConfig Settings Manager (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager; ccsm;`). Open the settings for "Ubuntu Unity Plugin", click the "Decorations" tab, then check and uncheck "Override Theme Settings". This way requires more work, but doesn't involve your desktop disappearing for a few seconds.

  [image]