# How to restart configuration

Tags: 14.04

I made some configuration mistakes that I need to undo.
I was using Compizconfig and now I can't access my desktop.
I'm unable to access anything on my laptop.
I think I need to restart the configuration/system but not erase any data.
How can I do that?

Comment: quick research brought this here:
may help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/348438/how-can-i-reset-compiz-settings-to-default

Comment: **Please don't post the same question twice!** (A.k.a. Possible duplicate of [Cant use Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/682337/cant-use-ubuntu))

Answer (score 0):

i am having a simmilar Problem.
i am not sure this will work out. and i dont know what compizconfig is.

But i want to try this myself in the next days:

try oem-config-prepare
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/oem-config-prepare.8.html

you might need to install the package
sudo apt-get install oem-config

access you pc via one of the text consoles CRTL-ALT+F1 etc.
or boot into text mode

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/boot-into-text-console-ubuntu-linux-14-04/

good luck :-)